# Fixture doesn't get updated after ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm testing my Angular app with Jest. Here is simplified template of my component:

```
<div *ngIf="viewInitialized">
  <button
    class="button"
    (click)="onLogoutClicked()"
  >
    {{ changeTokenText }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Here is simplified code of the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'logout-qr-page',
  templateUrl: './logout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logout.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class LogoutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  viewInitialized = false;

  constructor(
    ...
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    ...
    this.viewInitialized = true;
  }

  onLogoutClicked(): void {
    ...
  }
}
```

And my tests are:

```
describe('TsdLogoutComponent', () => {
  let component: LogoutComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LogoutComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LogoutComponent],
      imports: [
       ...
      ],
      providers: [
       ...
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LogoutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should correctly render default state', () => {
    expect(component.viewInitialized).toBe(true); // PASS
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.button'))).not.toBeNull(); // FAIL
  });
});
```

So as you can see viewInitialized is true, but there is no element with class 'button'. AfterViewInit was called, it changed the value but did not update the fixture.

I tried:

- calling `fixture.detectChanges()` multiple times, calling it only inside test (not in before each), calling it in before each and in test;
- using `await fixture.whenStable()`, using it with `fixture.detectChanges()`;
- using `fixture.autoDetectChanges()`.

What worked:
The test starts passing if I do `component.viewInitialized = true` manualy (in test), if I use signal in the component (`viewInitialized = signal(false) => viewInitialized.set(true)`) or if i call `cdRef.detectChanges()` in ngAfterViewInit. But I don't really want to use any of these - in my project everything works perfectly without signals or cdRef, I want it to work the same in tests or at least I want to understand the reason of this behavior.

Comment: Setting a variable in `ngAfterViewInit`  is an antipattern. You shouldn't do that. Even more when it's effecting the template.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I agree with you and maybe will change it, but still want to understand why it works differently

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue since this tests triggers a NG0100.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I don't have that error when I run my code. If changeDetection is not set as ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush - it triggers an error, but in my example I specifically indicated that ChangeDetectionStrategy is onPush. I think that is the reason why you was not able to reproduce my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and the issue most likely is because of:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

Apparently, with `OnPush` change detection, in unit tests you can only call `fixture.detectChanges()` once. After the first call, no matter how many times you call `fixture.detectChanges()`, the view won't get updated.

This article explains it: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-write-tests-for-components-with-onpush-change-detection-in-angular-24f2637a0f40.

You may need an account to read the article but the gist of it is to create a new function:

```
/**
 * Changes in components using OnPush strategy are only applied once when calling .detectChanges(),
 * This function solves this issue.
 */
export async function runOnPushChangeDetection(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>): Promise<void> {
  const changeDetectorRef = fixture.debugElement.injector.get<ChangeDetectorRef>(ChangeDetectorRef);
  changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  return fixture.whenStable();
}
```

In your test:

```
it('should correctly render default state', async () => {
    expect(component.viewInitialized).toBe(true); // PASS
    await runOnPushChangeDetection(fixture);
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.button'))).not.toBeNull(); // FAIL
  });
```

Can also use it in `fakeAsync/tick` way:

```
it('should correctly render default state', fakeAsync(() => {
    expect(component.viewInitialized).toBe(true); // PASS
    runOnPushChangeDetection(fixture);
    tick();
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.button'))).not.toBeNull(); // FAIL
  }));
```

Comment: nicely sumed up !